# Sum of sums then Group by?

Tags: sql

Can't figure out how to enact this formula, then get the answer by year.

```
Select
((Select Sum(#FinancialView2.CONVERTED_AMOUNT)*-1
FROM   #FinancialView2
WHERE  #FinancialView2."SECTION_NUMBER"=300 
AND #FinancialView2.BU_CODE in ('10','11','W0')
GROUP BY FinancialYear) 
+
(Select Sum(#FinancialView2.CONVERTED_AMOUNT)*-1
FROM   #FinancialView2
WHERE  #FinancialView2."SECTION_NUMBER"=400 
AND #FinancialView2.BU_CODE in ('10','11','W0')
AND #FinancialView2.DeptCode not in ('403','413')))
/
((Select Sum(#FinancialView2.CONVERTED_AMOUNT)*-1
FROM   #FinancialView2
WHERE  #FinancialView2."LINE_NUMBER"=110 
AND #FinancialView2.BU_CODE in ('10','11','W0')) 
+
(Select Sum(#FinancialView2.CONVERTED_AMOUNT)*-1
FROM   #FinancialView2
WHERE  #FinancialView2."LINE_NUMBER"=115 
AND #FinancialView2.BU_CODE in ('10','11','W0'))
+
(Select Sum(#FinancialView2.CONVERTED_AMOUNT)*-1
FROM   #FinancialView2
WHERE  #FinancialView2."LINE_NUMBER"=120
AND #FinancialView2.BU_CODE in ('10','11','W0')) 
+
(Select ISNULL(Sum(#FinancialView2.CONVERTED_AMOUNT)*-1,0)
FROM   #FinancialView2
WHERE  #FinancialView2."LINE_NUMBER"=125
AND #FinancialView2.BU_CODE in ('10','11','W0')))*-1
```

I tried 'Group By' here but it won't work for obvious reasons

Any thoughts?

Comment: A lot of thoughts to be honest. Could you explain the problem/goal of this script? Then paste the current error message and finally tell us which RDBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Loks like you need some conditional aggregate (double check if I translated the conditions correctly) :

```
Select FinancialYear,
 (
   Sum(CASE WHEN #FinancialView2."SECTION_NUMBER"=300
            THEN #FinancialView2.CONVERTED_AMOUNT ELSE 0 END)*-1
+  Sum(CASE WHEN #FinancialView2."SECTION_NUMBER"=400 AND #FinancialView2.DeptCode not in ('403','413')
            THEN #FinancialView2.CONVERTED_AMOUNT ELSE 0 END)*-1
  )
/
 (
   Sum(CASE WHEN #FinancialView2."SECTION_NUMBER"=110
            THEN #FinancialView2.CONVERTED_AMOUNT ELSE 0 END)*-1
+  Sum(CASE WHEN #FinancialView2."SECTION_NUMBER"=115
            THEN #FinancialView2.CONVERTED_AMOUNT ELSE 0 END)*-1
+  Sum(CASE WHEN #FinancialView2."SECTION_NUMBER"=120
            THEN #FinancialView2.CONVERTED_AMOUNT ELSE 0 END)*-1
+  Sum(CASE WHEN #FinancialView2."SECTION_NUMBER"=125
            THEN #FinancialView2.CONVERTED_AMOUNT ELSE 0 END)*-1
 )
WHERE #FinancialView2.BU_CODE in ('10','11','W0')
GROUP BY FinancialYear
```

This can be further simplified to:

```
Select FinancialYear,
 (
   Sum(CASE WHEN #FinancialView2."SECTION_NUMBER"=300
              OR (#FinancialView2."SECTION_NUMBER"=400 AND #FinancialView2.DeptCode not in ('403','413'))
            THEN #FinancialView2.CONVERTED_AMOUNT ELSE 0 END)*-1
 )
/
 (
   Sum(CASE WHEN #FinancialView2."SECTION_NUMBER" IN (110, 115, 120, 125)
            THEN #FinancialView2.CONVERTED_AMOUNT ELSE 0 END)*-1
 )
WHERE #FinancialView2.BU_CODE in ('10','11','W0')
GROUP BY FinancialYear
```

Finally, `col*-1` is exactly the same as `-col`

Comment: Your a champ bro, that really hit the spot